# Writing/reading Google Docs Spreadsheet with apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I need to write to a Google docs spreadsheet through a HTML form. How would you create a new row in an existing spreadsheet and insert the post data in a doPost to that row in specified columns? How would you read or query the spreadsheet to retrieve that same data?

Answer (score 0):

Martin's got several blogs on it [here.](http://mashe.hawksey.info/2011/10/google-spreadsheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-form-postget-submit-method/)